# Unknown host entry in mysql user table

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select user,host, password from user
+------+-----------+----------+
| user | host      | password |
+------+-----------+----------+
| root | localhost |          |    
| root | 127.0.0.1 |          |
| root | ::1       |          |
|      | localhost |          | 
| pma  | localhost |          |
+------+-----------+----------+
```

What is the "::1" entry in column host? Is this an security issue I need to care about (no password set)

Comment: ::1 is IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1 (i.e. localhost).